# Activity stack and GC

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

When I start my app and press a button the takes me to another activity and I stay there a long time, can the previous activity be collected by the GC or is the previous activity being referenced by my current activity and keeps the GC from collecting it?

If it can be collected, what will happen when I press the "back" key? same this that happens when I change my screen orientation? will the status of the collected activity be kept?

Thanks.